# Can I access the custom data of a specific user with Stormpath?

Tags: node.js, express, stormpath

I am using Stormpath with Express and I want to access custom data of a specific user that exists in the database while not logged in as that user. This will be used in an admin-style UI where users with certain privileges can edit the custom data of other users.

How can I access the data of a specific user like I would access the current user's data using `req.user.customData`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using the express library you can do it by saying:

```
app.get('stormpathApplication').getAccount(account_href_here, function(err, account) {
  if (err) throw err;
  account.getCustomData(function(err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

`app.get('stormpathApplication')` is an Application object under the hood, so any of these API docs work on it: http://docs.stormpath.com/nodejs/api/application

I'm the developer of this library, hope this helps!

Comment: I am using the Express-Stormpath library. This helps. How can I look a user up by name, though?

Comment: To look a user up by name just say: app.get('stormpathApplication').getAccounts( { username: 'blah' }, function(err, accounts) { ... ]);

Comment: All these weeks later, I am trying this for the first time and it does not work. I seem to be able to get each account, but calling any Account function gives me an error saying that the callback has already been called. Like so: http://i.imgur.com/bVAVEYW.png. This is my code: http://i.imgur.com/goLbHLf.png.

Comment: Ah, your code isn't iterating over the accounts properly. Here's a working example: http://pastie.org/9981941

Comment: Thanks! Can I modify and save each user when iterating?